# How to sort array in mongo document field

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have mongo document and i am getting it with find_one

I actually dont need answer with python example. I can accept just a mongo query for that example

```
obj = await collection.find_one({'fields.uuid': obj_uuid})
```

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('65d5e666deda15bb37f308fe'),
    deleted: false,
    fields: {
        'uuid': 'some_uuid',
        'employees': [
          {
            "first_name": "Anna"
          },
          {
            "first_name": "Bob"
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

And i am wondering if there is the way to sort this array in field `employees`. For example Bob to be first or last in this array?

I know there mongo has an aggregation with replacing fields but this works only on list

Comment: Have you checked out [$sortArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$sortArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/) to sort `fields.employees` based on `first_name` using the [aggregate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/aggregate/) method like so:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "fields.uuid": "some_uuid"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "fields.employees": {
        $sortArray: {
          input: "$fields.employees",
          sortBy: {
            "first_name": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xDaqrRro9MU) for a working example.

The `$match` stage is synonymous with the query used in a regular `find` or `findOne` method. Using a `1` or `-1` for the sort reverses the order.